# Как избавится от дублирования кода в шаблоне template?

Tags: c++

Всем привет, мне нужно построить код внутри шаблона который тоже будет шаблоном
Вот мой код

```
class A
{
public:
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    A(T1 y, T2 d, T1 t, T2 f, T1 w, T2 l)
    {
     ofstream out;

     out.open(d, ofstream::app);
     out.write((char*)& y, sizeof(y));
     out.close();

     // очередная копия кода
     out.open(f, ofstream::app);
     out.write((char*)& t, sizeof(t));
     out.close();

     // снова копия о боже мой
     out.open(l, ofstream::app);
     out.write((char*)& w, sizeof(w));
     out.close();
    }
};
```

Как видите он находится внутри класса A и шаблона template
используя шаблон я вызываю эту функцию таким способом

```
int main()
{
    A(777, "1.bin", 666, "2.bin", 555, "3.bin");
}
```

Проблема в том что мне нужно создать много файлов но я не хочу каждый раз копировать код ofstream.

А так же я не могу использовать код не внутри класса A и шаблона template, все переменные и их работа выполняется только там.
Если я перемещаю этот код в отдельный класс он не может передавать прочитанные данные другой переменной или другому классу, получается все работает только внутри класса A и шаблона template.
Пытался создать наследования классов но один фиг классы хранят данные только внутри себя и не могут передавать данные между шаблона template.
Скорее всего я где то ошибся или чего то не знаю.
Надеюсь на подержу и много разных примеров.

Обновления для **AlexGlebe**

```
using namespace std;

public:
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
    A(T1 y, T2 d, T1 t, T2 f, T3 w, T4 l, T5 h, T2 r, T3 z, T4 n) {

      ifstream in;
      open_in<T3, T5>(in, y, d);

    // тут начинается другой код который дальше работает с переменными
    // например простой цикл который должен получить данные y и продолжить
    // свое выполнения подсчетов, но к сожалению он получает старые данные
    // которые были добавлены в main
    // A("1.bin", "2.bin", "3.bin", 666, 555, 111, 955635332, 333, 777, 10);

      ofstream out;
      open_out<T1,T2>(out, y,  d);

    }
private :
   // первый сохраняет
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void open_out(ofstream & out,T1 a, T2 b) {
              out.open(b, ofstream::app);
              out.write((char*)& a, sizeof(a));
              out.close();
    }

    // второй читаем данные
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void open_in(ifstream & in,T1 a, T2 b) {
              in.open(b, ios::binary);
              in.read((char*)& a, sizeof(a)))
              in.close();
    }

};

// main
A("1.bin", "2.bin", "3.bin", 666, 555, 111, 955635332, 333, 777, 10);
```

Код который читай данные не передает их на переменную **y** и **d** в итоге мы получаем старые данные, когда снова попадаем в класс A

И на самом деле я бы хотел вытащить это отдельно от класcа A иначе мне потом сложно будет работать с этим годом.

Comment: класс А не вижу. У вас шаблонная функция и нет никакого класса. Какое наследование, зачем  шаблон, когда вам нужна символьная строка? Вы все путаете

Comment: @ARHovsepyan исправил, просто не добавлял думал не нужен.

Comment: Честно, я ничего не понел. Конкретно что вы хотите получить? 
Не понятно понятие "внутри шаблона "

Comment: @ARHovsepyan еще раз внес изменения посмотрите

Comment: Я показываю это на маленьких примерах на самом деле мой ofstream  очень огромный с кучами функций

Comment: Непонятно, зачем здесь понадобился шаблонный класс...

Comment: Почему вы не можете создать ещё 1 шаблонный метод, в который запихнуть то, что вы копируете. А в  методе `A` вызывать кучу раз его.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко можно пример

Comment: @AnT шаблон обязательно нужен то что вы видите выше это простенький пример

Comment: Я может и туплю, но я не понел, вы хотите в классе хранить ссыльки на  все файлы или что?

Comment: Я понимаю, что шаблон нужен. Но почему здесь вдруг используется шаблонный *класс*? Почему не просто шаблонная функция?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да только в классе A или создать что то внутри класса A и взаимодействовать с ним.

Comment: @AnT там мне для циклов он нужен

Comment: Почему не написать одну шаблонную функцию с двумя параметрами?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Может я не понял, но вот мой ответ:

```
# include <fstream>
class A
{
public:
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    A(T1 y, T2 d, T1 t, T2 f, T1 w, T2 l)
    {
     std::ofstream out;

     openwriteclose<T1,T2>(out, y,  d);
     openwriteclose<T1,T2>(out, t,  f);
     openwriteclose<T1,T2>(out, w,  l);

    }
private :
template <typename T1, typename T2>
  void openwriteclose(std::ofstream & out,T1 y, T2 d){
    out.open(d, std::ofstream::app);
    out.write((char*)& y, sizeof(y));
    out.close();  }
};

int main()
{
    A(777, "1.bin", 666, "2.bin", 555, "3.bin");
}
```

Второй вариант со списком любого размера :

```
 # include <fstream>
# include <list>
class A
{
public:
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    A(std::list<std::pair<T1,T2>> & list)
    {
     std::ofstream out;
     for(std::pair<T1,T2> & j : list){
       out.open(j.second, std::ofstream::app);
      out.write((char*)& j.first, sizeof(j.first));
      out.close();    }     
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::list<std::pair<int,char const * > > args={{777, "1.bin"},{ 666, "2.bin"},{ 555, "3.bin"}};
    A a(args);
}
```

Comment: это явно не будет работать с моим кодом

Comment: Хотя надо попробовать возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: вот вам список аргументов

Comment: Не это походу чет не то, предыдущий вариант верните :)

Comment: Хотя пусть 2 вариант будут сейчас проверю

Comment: карочи первый вариант подходит кажись очень хорошо единственно я запутался с шаблоном template :)
просто он повторяется у вас, может лучше использовать один шаблон 
A(T1 y, T2 d, T1 t, T2 f, T1 w, T2 l)

Второй вариант который вы описали я даже не знаю я не использовал не разу list и он какой то сложный для понимания

Comment: Первый вариант самый лучший и интуитивно понятный, пушку просто.
Он использует private и да он работает отлично.

Comment: Есть небольшой недостаток ifstream почему то не передает информацию в public переменную, возможно я чет не так реализовал

Comment: Как я могу получить область видимости между двух разных template один в public другой в private

Comment: Скорее всего это уже другой вопрос, нужно выложить все исходиники, чтоб вам всё объяснили.

Comment: Я боюсь что мне снова придется объяснять чего я хочу.
Но если вам нужно представления, смотрите в описания сейчас добавлю 5 минут.

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите сейчас

Comment: Все сделал все сам, вот так
`void open_out(ofstream& output_file, T1& a, const T2& b)`

Answer (score 0):

Все варианты, что пришли в голову, как мог написал.

В шаблонах я не эксперт, поэтому variadic templates написал как умел.

Тут на выбор три варианта:

1. Использовать оператор `<<`.
2. Использовать метод `write`, который возвращает ссылку на объект, и позволяет сделать цепочку вызовов
3. Variadic templates, почти то что вы хотели.

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Example{
public:

    template<typename T>
    const Example& write(const T& y, const std::string& d) const{
        std::ofstream out;
        out.open(d, std::ofstream::app);
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&y), sizeof(y));
        out.close();
        return *this;
    }

    struct FilePath{
        std::string filepath;
    };

    template<typename T>
    Example& operator<<(const T& t){
        std::ofstream out;
        out.open(m_filepath, std::ofstream::app);
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
        out.close();
        return *this;
    }

    Example& operator<<(const FilePath& fp){
        m_filepath = fp.filepath;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct DataForWriteToFile{
        T data;
        std::string filepath;
    };

    template<typename... Args>
    void writeToFile(Args... args){
        writeToFile(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void writeToFile(const DataForWriteToFile<T>& t, Args... args){
        write(t.data, t.filepath);
        writeToFile(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template<typename T>
    void writeToFile(const DataForWriteToFile<T>& t){
        write(t.data, t.filepath);
    }


private:
    std::string m_filepath = "tmp.bin";

};


int main(){
    Example e;
    using Data = Example::DataForWriteToFile<int>;
    e.write(777, "1.bin").write(666, "2.bin").write(555, "3.bin");
    e << Example::FilePath{"11.bin"} << 777 << Example::FilePath{"22.bin"} << 666 << Example::FilePath{"33.bin"} << 555;
    e.writeToFile(Data{777, "111.bin"}, Data{666, "222.bin"}, Data{555, "333.bin"});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как то все не читаемое, можно один пример самый лучший что бы каши не было и поменьше кода.

Comment: как я понял Example повторно вызывает ofstream out; его просто нет смысла повторно вызывать, можно один раз

Comment: `e.writeToFile(Data{777, "111.bin"}, Data{666, "222.bin"}, Data{555, "333.bin"});` - вот эта строчка в main ближе всего к тому что вы хотели. Я не эксперт в шаблонах, и вообще считаю что лучше просто список данных в метод отдавать в виде `std::list<DataForWrite>` и всё, а внутри метода уже в цикле их обработать.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за вариант, но он какой то очень нестандартный мне бы с поддержкой ООП и более интуитивный, конечно я попробую улучшить вашу работу но пока как то выглядит мягко сказать плохо.

Comment: Вы сами плохо оформили вопрос, потому и получите не тот ответ, что вам поможет или не получите ответ. Старайтесь ясно выразить что вы хотите получать в итоге

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вероятно всего, я не отрицаю но постарался объяснить как мог

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант с функтором, принимающим два параметра:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

class BatchWrite
{
    public: template<typename Data, typename Path> BatchWrite && 
    operator ()(Data const & data, Path const & path) const
    {
        static_assert(::std::is_standard_layout_v<Data>);
        ::std::ofstream out{};
        out.exceptions(::std::ofstream::badbit bitor ::std::ofstream::failbit bitor ::std::ofstream::eofbit);
        out.open(path, ::std::ofstream::app bitor ::std::ofstream::binary);
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(::std::addressof(data)), sizeof(data));
        return ::std::move(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BatchWrite{}(777, "1.bin")(666, "2.bin")(555, "3.bin");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95414/discussion-on-answer-by-vtt--------templat).